# Could not find org.datanucleus.store_mapping extension in datanucleus-core-4.0

Tags: java, datanucleus

I tried to follow http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/guides/user_types/index.html but could not find extension org.datanucleus.store_mapping as mentioned in step 4. Can anybody help please?

Thanks in advance.

(I could not find a corresponding guide for version 4.)

Comment: why use a guide for v3.1 of DataNucleus when you use v4.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, all DataNucleus extension points are adequately defined in individual guides like
http://www.datanucleus.org/documentation/extensions/rdbms_java_types.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, let me tell the problem I am trying to fix. I'm using datanucleus and mongodb... and I want to persist my own type (which extends java.util.Set) but not able to. It throws exception. What should I be doing?

Comment: You should be presenting your ACTUAL problem in its own separate question, and adding an extension for RDBMS (what that extension is for) won't be much help to you if using MongoDB. DataNucleus v4 uses TypeConverters for supporting types, for all datastores AFAIK (so including MongoDB)

Comment: I have created a separate question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107164/persisting-user-type-with-datanucleus. But, TypeConverters seems more like a workaround to fix my problem. store_mapping looked to me like a solution actually but could not find such thing for v4 :(

Comment: as already said "store_mapping" is for RDBMS only and always has been, and I pointed out above where it is in v4.0