# Persisting user type with DataNucleus

Tags: java, mongodb, datanucleus

I'm using datanucleus with mongodb. I want to persist my own type (which extends java.util.Set) but not able to. It throws exception. What should I be doing?

Here is the code:

My custom object which is part of my object which I want to persist - CustomSet.java

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class CustomSet<E> implements Set<E> {
    private final Set<E> hashSet = new HashSet<E>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return hashSet.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return hashSet.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return hashSet.contains(o);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return hashSet.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return hashSet.toArray();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        return hashSet.toArray(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return hashSet.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o) {
        return hashSet.remove(o);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return hashSet.containsAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        return hashSet.addAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return hashSet.retainAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
        return hashSet.removeAll(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        hashSet.clear();
    }

}
```

My Object which I want to persist - MyDBObject.java

```
import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(detachable = "true")
public class MyDBObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.UUIDHEX)
    private String id;

    @Persistent
    private String name = null;

    @Persistent
    private CustomSet<String> set = null;

    public MyDBObject(String name, CustomSet<String> set) {
        this.name = name;
        this.set = set;
    }
}
```

A test code to show the problem:

```
public class Test {
    private final static PersistenceManagerFactory pmFactory = JDOHelper
            .getPersistenceManagerFactory(new File("appdb.properties"));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomSet<String> set = new CustomSet<>();
        set.add("Test-1");
        set.add("Test-2");
        set.add("Test-3");
        saveOrUpdate(pmFactory.getPersistenceManager(), new MyDBObject(
                "TestObject", set));
    }

    public static <T> void saveOrUpdate(PersistenceManager pm, T object) {
        Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
        try {
            tx.begin();
            pm.makePersistent(object);
            tx.commit();
        } finally {
            if (tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            pm.close();
        }
    }
}
```

After executing the above code I am getting the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datanucleus.store.types.wrappers.Collection cannot be cast to test.beans.CustomSet
    at test.beans.MyDBObject.dnReplaceField(MyDBObject.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.replaceField(StateManagerImpl.java:1910)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.replaceField(StateManagerImpl.java:3112)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.replaceField(StateManagerImpl.java:3015)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.SCOUtils.createSCOWrapper(SCOUtils.java:233)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.SCOUtils.newSCOInstance(SCOUtils.java:135)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.wrapSCOField(StateManagerImpl.java:3378)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.fieldmanager.StoreFieldManager.storeNonEmbeddedObjectField(StoreFieldManager.java:569)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.fieldmanager.StoreFieldManager.storeObjectField(StoreFieldManager.java:505)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.providedObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:1457)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.providedObjectField(StateManagerImpl.java:117)
    at test.beans.MyDBObject.dnProvideField(MyDBObject.java)
    at test.beans.MyDBObject.dnProvideFields(MyDBObject.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.provideFields(StateManagerImpl.java:1198)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBPersistenceHandler.getDBObjectForObjectProviderToInsert(MongoDBPersistenceHandler.java:388)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBPersistenceHandler.insertObject(MongoDBPersistenceHandler.java:220)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.internalMakePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:3489)
    at org.datanucleus.state.StateManagerImpl.makePersistent(StateManagerImpl.java:3465)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectInternal(ExecutionContextImpl.java:2031)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObjectWork(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1874)
    at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.persistObject(ExecutionContextImpl.java:1722)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:722)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:747)
    at test.Test.saveOrUpdate(Test.java:30)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:22)

Comment: Firstly I don't see the point in having your own "HashSet". Secondly if you really need it, then where is your wrapper (proxy) class for this "Set"? Any container class (Collection, Map) has to have a wrapper so that changes can be detected to it. Look in DataNucleus core codebase and you will find some at https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-core/tree/master/src/main/java/org/datanucleus/store/types/wrappers

Comment: @NeilStockton, writing a wrapper looks quite a bit of a task. For example in ArrayList wrapper class I see few methods are synchronized but few are not and also each wrapper class has a corresponding "backing store"... I don't know how to wire this all together to achieve the simple goal. Any tutorial link you have please?

Comment: you dont need a backing store ... you're using MongoDB. If you use the ones at the link i gave (and dont navigate into "backed") then you have the right ones. These are all extension points "java_type" IIRC